# Piping VSCode output to another program

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, console, escaping, special-characters

Frustratingly there is an [old issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98471) that has been closed in relation to this. The linked issues seem to resolve this for python extensions, but I am using Typescript. No comments on it being resolved in general when it was closed so I assume that there must be a way to achieve this.

I wish to use VSCode debugging with individual test files, but also pipe the final output to a different program. VSCode escapes the pipe operator...

launch.json

```json
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "tap-single",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "program": "${file}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/home/user/.npm-global/bin/ts-node",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--transpileOnly",
      ],
      "args": [
        "|",      // This is output as `\|` in the console...
        "tap-arc"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
```

Partial output is below;

```
... /home/user/.npm-global/bin/ts-node --transpileOnly ./test/example.test.ts \| tap-arc 
Debugger attached.
```

Comment: Then make a custom task?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If the node task schema isn't flexible enough to do what you want, find one that is. Ex. [the `shell` type](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks).